# Cannot read property of type null with async map

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I am mapping over data and pushing it into an array. The map works at first and the values are showing up in the console (arr array value). However afterwards it clears data and shows up as testauth map is undefined could someone please help?

```
  const [personInfo, setPersonInfo] = useState(null)
  const [testauth, setTestauth] =useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getPersons() {
      loading.setLoading(true)
      const personsResults = await get('get_persons_autocomplete/a', user.user)
      const results = await get(`get_authorities_autocomplete/a`, user.user)
      setTestauth(results)

      loading.setLoading(false)
      autoComplete.setAuthoritiesAutoComplete(results)
      autoComplete.setPersonsAutoComplete(personsResults)
    }
    getPersons()
  }, [])

const asyncFunc = async () => {
  const arr = []

  testauth.map(e => {
      arr.push(e.value)
      console.log('pushed value',arr);
    })
};
```

[image]

The screen is normal for a few seconds then After a few seconds I get this error:
[image]

Comment: can you attach whole codebase that shows error?

Comment: @WilliamWang no worries. I updated, the question.

Comment: where is the `testauth`  ?

Comment: in a state variable which returns results from a get request.

Comment: just updated @kyun

Comment: And when `asyncFunc()` called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the javascript method of the array object, so you need to check if array is not null before call `map` method.

In your example, you can't guarantee that `testauth` is always array, and it can be `null` value.

```
const asyncFunc = async () => {
  const arr = []

  testauth && testauth.map(e => {
      arr.push(e.value)
      console.log('pushed value',arr);
    })
};
```

---

FYI, the way you used `map` is the the correct way. `map` returns an transformed array with the same length of the input array.
You need to use as follows:

```
const asyncFunc = async () => {
  const arr = testauth? testauth.map(e => e.value) : []
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If `asyncFunc` is declared in the same scope as that `useEffect`, then I believe you're accidentally closing over the current value of `testauth` (which is null when this starts) when you create the function.

Create it as a callback instead:

```
const asyncFunc = useCallback(async () => {
  const arr = []

  testauth.map(e => {
      arr.push(e.value)
      console.log('pushed value',arr);
    })
}, [testauth]);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Am I able to map over this in the usEffect?

Comment: As long as you add `asyncFunc` as a dependency of the effect, then yes. Otherwise you will simply close over the current value of `asyncFunc` (introducing effectively the same problem) when the function you pass to the effect is created.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
const asyncFunc = async () => {
  const arr = []

  testauth?.map(e => {
      arr.push(e.value)
      console.log('pushed value',arr);
    })
};
```

By the way, I don't think it is good way to iterate with `map()`.
Because `map()` returns array.

So, If you want to iterate only, you should better to use `forEach()`

```
testauth?.forEach(e => {
  arr.push(e.value)
  console.log('pushed value',arr);
})
```